# Blazor - Unable to read config files from NavMenu component

Tags: c#, configuration, blazor-server-side

I am working on a Blazor server app and am having an issue reading my config files from the NavMenu component.  I have the config bound to a custom object and I am using that around my application, this works fine.  Now I need to add a link in the NavMenu who's URL is dynamic based on the environment.  I have all my variables set up correctly, as I said, this works on other pages, but when I try to read from my custom object, or the config variable directly, they are null at this point.  I am assuming this is some sort of timing issue getting the config information.  I can read the environment variable and can hard code the link for each environment with a switch, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.  Does anyone have any ideas or workarounds to get this to work?

```
        [Inject]
        protected WebConfiguration WebConfiguration { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        protected IConfiguration Config { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; set; }
```

This what I have tried, and in my code-behind, the only variable that is filled is the Environment variable

Comment: [Inject] works only on Components, is it your custom object a Component?

Comment: This is in the NavMenu component that the Visual Studio creates by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to give an update for anyone with the same issue.  It turns out that someone renamed the appsettings.Devlopment.config file to appsettings.DEV.config.  I am assuming that .NET core only likes certain names.  Because of that, the IConfiguration values were not populated.  I now need to find out if there is a way to use custom environment names.

Thanks to anyone who took a look at this.

Comment: You can specify custom environment variabbles within your projects propteries. You'll need to read them then in your progam.cs and load the corresponding .json files.